# Cartoon where kid finds a microscopic world of "Battle Bugs"

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I was wondering if anyone knows this show about a high school kid who finds a hidden microscopic world of “Battle Bugs” and he can control them with this Game Boy-looking thing.

I tried googling something similar to the text above or googling “shows like Digimon.”

There is also some “mad scientist” type guy as the villain.

They also made a toy out of it from what I remember.

The show didn’t last long I think, and I remember watching it on YouTube.

Comment: Probably not Pokémon.